# How to set up XSLT 2.0 in Tomcat?

Tags: xslt, tomcat, xslt-2.0

Right now I am trying to set up XSLT 2.0 with Tomcat. Is that possible? Please guide me.

Regards

Karthic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just copy saxon9he.jar into the lib directory of the web application, and you are ready to go. If you want to use Saxon Enterprise Edition, install saxon9ee.jar instead, along with the license file from Saxonica.

If you're using JAXP APIs rather than Saxon's s9api API (s9api is better suited to exploiting XSLT 2.0 functionality) then you will need to make sure your application invokes Saxon rather than Xalan. The best way to do this is to instantiate the TransformerFactory directly: for Saxon-HE, use

```
TransformerFactory factory = new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl();
```

in place of the usual

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

which loads whatever XSLT engine it finds first on the classpath.

Comment: Hi @Michael Kay thank you very much i will check and let you know